# How to make each input in an int cstring a single digit?

Tags: c++, int, cstring, digit

What I need to do, is input an int c string from the keyboard, but each digit should be a single digit int.

For example in the running program if I would input "1234", it shouldn't read '1234', but a '1' followed by a '2', '3' and then '4'. I would submit my thought process on it, but I'm at a complete loss here.

This is in C++ by the way, and I have the restriction of not being able to use anything from the STL library.

Comment: If it quacks like a homework...

Comment: Read a CHAR instead of string, then convert to correct int. Or, read a string with width manipulator of 1 (assuming I remember correctly that cin adheres to them :P)

Comment: `I would submit my thought process on it, but I'm at a complete loss here.` Do it anyway!

Comment: One option is to read as a number and use math to isolate the digits.

Comment: Yeah it is a homework, I guess I should have said so. I was trying to do a do... while loop, but I don't think that would have reached anywhere, the char answer seems to be viable, I'll try that. Thank you very much quetzalcoalt!

Comment: Read into a string, subtract `'0'` from each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say we have a char array of that you've gotten from the user, and that array of chars looks something like this `char line[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};` which is basically equivalent of entering `1234` in the console.

it would then be possible to get the integer value of an indexed position in the previously mentioned array by doing something like this: `int one = line[0] - '0';`

this:

```
char line[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
int one = line[0] - '0';
std::cout << one << std::endl;
```

will output this:

`1`